# Is there any way to block a specific software from detecting or using a specific hardware? Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, permissions, gaming, game-controller

I want to use Xpadder to play a game that atomatically detects my Xbox 360 controller even if I conect it after launch or reconect it during gameplay. The controller can't be disabled in-game so I was wondering if theres a software that does what I asked in my question.

Comment: What problem are you specifically trying to solve?

Comment: I have a game that automatically detects my Xbox 360 controller. Even if I connect it after launch, disconnect and reconnect after launch. Nothing works to keep this game from detecting my controller. I can't disable controller detection in the game's options. Since the native controller support is horrendous, I wanted to use Xpadder (third party software) to map my own bindings. Sadly, since the game always detect my controller, I can't configure it well. I wanted to know if theres a way to prevent a specific application (only the game) from detecting a specific hardware (the controller).

Comment: I am guessing what makes Xpadder detect the controller is exactly what makes the game detect it. Your not going to be able to disable the controller for one without disabling it for all.

Comment: :( so there is no way to choose which application can or can't use hardware?

Comment: Can't you just disable the controller in Device Manager when you want to launch the game, then re-enable it when your done? There is no process I am aware of to do this automatically.

Comment: As I said before, I want to use Xpadder: I don't want to disable it for the whole system, just for the game. If I disable it on the device manager I won't be able to use it with Xpadder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [HidHide](https://github.com/ViGEm/HidHide) it is possible to deny a specific application access to one or more human interface devices, effectively hiding a device from the application.